# Can't Show Video Frames in picture box

Tags: c#, aforge

I upload video in my c# project by AForge FFMPEG, but when I try to show video frames in picture box I get Exception that say  "Parameter is not valid"

This is my Code:

```
        VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();        

        reader.Open(txtPath.Text.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FrameCount; i++)
        {
              Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();

              pictureBox1.Image = videoFrame;   

              videoFrame.Dispose();
        }
        reader.Close();
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not dispose the image, as it will also clears it from the picture box.

Also, you are doing it in a loop. During this, the ui will not update. Use a Timer instead, and in each timer tick, read one frame.